# How to open a tty device in noncanonical mode on Linux using .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, embedded-linux, tty, termios

I'm using .NET Core on an embedded Linux platform with good success so far. I just ran into a problem with trying to open a tty device in raw (noncanonical mode) though. If I was using regular C or C++ I would call `cfmakeraw()` after opening the device, but how do I do that from a .NET Core app?

The device I need to work with is a CDC ACM function driver for the USB client connector, i.e. it's a virtual COM port. It appears in my system as `/dev/ttyGS0`. I can open the device and then read from it and write to it using this code:

`FileStream vcom = new FileStream("/dev/ttyGS0", FileMode.Open);`

Because the tty device opens in canonical mode by default I don't receive any characters until the user sends the carriage return character at the end of the line of text. I need to receive each character as it is sent, rather than waiting untill the carriage return is sent, i.e. I need to use raw mode for the tty device.

The code below does not work because .NET Core does not realize that this device is a virtual serial port, so it throws an exception when I try to open it this way. When I open the real UART devices using `SerialPort` then they do behave in raw mode as expected.

`SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyGS0);`

Comment: Try shell command  `stty -F /dev/ttyGS0 raw` before you run your program.  Use  `stty -F /dev/ttyGS0 sane` to restore.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I extended it to suppress echoing characters using ```sty -F /dev/ttyGS0 raw -echo```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a terminal device, you could try to alter its termios configuration prior to actually using it.
Try issuing the shell command `stty -F /dev/ttyGS0 raw` before you run your program.

The `raw` setting will make the following termios changes (according to the **stty** man page) for noncanonical mode:

```
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixany -ixoff -imaxbel 
-opost 
-icanon -isig -xcase -iuclc  
min 1 time 0
```

Note that no **c_cflag** attributes (e.g. baudrate, parity, character size) nor echo attributes (as you already know) are changed by the `raw` setting.

For comparison the libc [cfmakeraw()](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/termios/cfmakeraw.c.html) routine that you mention makes the following termios settings:

```
  t->c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL|IXON);
  t->c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
  t->c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ECHONL|ICANON|ISIG|IEXTEN);
  t->c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE|PARENB);
  t->c_cflag |= CS8;
  t->c_cc[VMIN] = 1;      /* read returns when one char is available.  */
  t->c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
```

---

You can use `stty -F /dev/ttyGS0 sane` to restore the terminal to a default termios configuration.